# Pre-defined widgets on Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have been using Apostrophe CMS and it is great. What I want to do is have widgets pre-defined on the page without the user adding those widgets and for those widgets to have placeholder data. For example, I want apostrophe-images to already be on the page in an area and have a placeholder image. The user would then change the content to suit their needs. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A somewhat brittle way to accomplish this would be to hook into `apostrophe-pages` `beforeInsert` method and detect some condition you want to apply the sample data, then populate the appropriate properties with your sample JSON.

1. Populate a page as you'd like to see it when created for the first time by an editor.
2. Copy the JSON from your pre-populated properties from the database as Apostrophe would store it (`db.aposDocs.find({slug: '/sample'}` or whatever).
3. Anywhere you see an `_id` field being copied from your sample, replace it with `self.apos.utils.generateId()` (don't replace id's of content you are actually referencing)
4. in `lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js`

```
module.exports = {
  types: [
    {
      name: 'default',
      label: 'Default'
    }
    // .. other page types
  ],
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.beforeInsert = function(req, page, options, callback) {

      ////////////
      // Should i pre populate this new page with sample data?
      if (page.type === 'default') {
        page.body = {
          "type" : "area",
          "items" : [
            {
              "by" : "id",
              "_id" : self.apos.utils.generateId(),
              "pieceIds" : [
                "ck2z5b8y0002xs6q7jcthp2ds"
              ],
              "relationships" : {
                "ck2z5b8y0002xs6q7jcthp2ds" : {
                  "left" : null,
                  "top" : null,
                  "width" : null,
                  "height" : null,
                  "x" : null,
                  "y" : null
                }
              },
              "type" : "apostrophe-images"
            },
            {
              "_id" : self.apos.utils.generateId(),
              "type" : "apostrophe-rich-text",
              "content" : "<p><strong><em>Authors often misinterpret the mom as a surest quilt, when in actuality it feels more like a rimless jeep. Far from the truth, an iffy russia without porcupines is truly a sycamore of jessant farmers.</em></strong></p>\n\n<p> </p>\n"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
      return setImmediate(callback);
    };
  }
};
```

This would pre populate a page's `body` property with an area that contains an `apostrophe-images` widget and a `apostrophe-rich-text` widget.

You could further clamp down this behavior by adding a field on your interesting page type that let an editor opt out of this behavior and check it on your `beforeInsert` condition.

Again, this example is a bit rigid because you're hardcoding image piece ids into the `beforeInsert` .. You could further get fancy by running a query for images with a certain tag ('sample'), generating lorem ipsum text with external modules, etc. before populating your property.