# Add pre-defined widgets to home

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59109019/pre-defined-widgets-on-apostrophe-cms) which was really useful for me to have some pre-defined widgets on newly created pages.

```js
// lib/modules/apostrophe-pages/index.js

  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.beforeInsert = function(req, page, options, callback) {
      page.navigationArea = {
        "type" : "area",
        "items" : [
          {
            "by" : "id",
            "limitByAll" : 5,
            "limitByTag" : 5,
            "navShadow" : false,
            "linksArray" : [ ],
            "_id" : self.apos.utils.generateId(),
            "nav" : "default",
            "pieceIds" : [ ],
            "logoId" : null,
            "navBackgroundImageId" : null,
            "navColor" : null,
            "navTextColor" : null,
            "gradientColorTop" : null,
            "gradientColorBottom" : null,
            "tags" : [ ],
            "type" : "navigations"
          }
        ]
      }
      return setImmediate(callback);
    };
  }
```

But this adds the `navigationArea` only on pages I create. Home which is created at startup seems to be excluded from that. The Home will have `navigationArea` empty at first startup and I need to add it manually. How can I make sure that the function `self.beforeInsert` is also applied to home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if this was added before the database was ever created then `beforeInsert` would cover it. Since there wasn't a home page yet, it would be inserted when the app first starts up. But let's assume you already created the app.

This might be job for a migration. You could [write a migration](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/advanced-topics/migrations.html) that looks for the home page (`slug: '/'`) and looks to see if that area is empty. If it is, then update the doc with your data. It should only run once since migrations are tracked in a database collection. Even if it does run again, as long as you are querying only "home pages" that don't yet have the data, you'll be safe.

Comment: I expected the same behavior but sadly that's not the case. I've deleted the db with `db.dropDatabase()` and still home won't be populated. Thx for the hint about migrations,  l learned here a lot about apostrophe, which will be certainly useful in some other cases, but here I wouldn't need that. My question is regarded only to first creation of db.

Comment: The migration method could help even on creation. It would depend a bit on startup order, but could be worth trying.